# Circular progress amount in the center of the circle? (angular material)

Tags: css, angular-material, progress-bar, material-design

I'm using the circular-progress-bar element of angular material and trying to set the amount of progress in the center of the circle, but it went out bad. 
Some talented, gifted front-end developer maybe know how to do it? 
Thanks in advance.

```html
<md-progress-circular layout-padding value="{{vm.progress}}" md-diameter="95" md-mode="determinate"> {{vm.progress}}%</md-progress-circular>
//how the hack should i css it to be in the middle :( ?
        <h4>{{vm.progress}}%</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/mAXrGm)

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <div style="width:{{vm.diameter}}px; height:{{vm.diameter}}px">
    <md-progress-circular md-diameter="{{vm.diameter}}" md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.progress}}">
    </md-progress-circular>
    <h4 id="progress">{{vm.progress}}%</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.diameter = 200;
  this.progress = 83;
});
```

CSS

```
#progress {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Comment: Hi man, unfortunately the location of the "progress" is depend on the screen size, for i.e - when the development tool ("inspect") is open' the progress relocated accordingly, which might not be in the center. what would you recommend to do about it? thanks again

Comment: You ll have to use a media queries for that purpose .